# Codificar/decodificar caracteres especiales (tíldes, ñ) en python-gimp

Tags: python, python-2.7, gimp

He escrito una función en python para simular el [efecto de escribir](https://github.com/G0erman/GIMP-Python) en un [GIF](http://es-goerman.blogspot.com.co/2017/02/automatizar-creacion-de-gif-con-gimp.html), la cual funciona excepto para caracteres especiales como tíldes y eñes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Función**

```
def efecto_escritura(x, y, color,texto):
    texto_completo = texto
    ultimo_texto=''
    imagen_inicial = gimp.image_list()[0]    
    #Color del texto 
    gimp.set_foreground(color)

    # Parámetros Fuente
    fontname= 'Sans' #Tipo de letra
    size_type=PIXELS 
    size= 30 #Tamaño
    antialias = True
    border = 0
    #y = 0 
    #x = 0 
    drawable = None
    image = imagen_inicial    
    for i in texto_completo:
        ultimo_texto=ultimo_texto+i
        layer = pdb.gimp_text_fontname(image, drawable, x, y, ultimo_texto, border, antialias, size, size_type, fontname)
        print(ultimo_texto)
```

**Uso**

Ejecutar en "Python Console" de GIMP

```
efecto_escritura(58,209,(255, 255, 255), 'Stackoverflow en español')
```

**Mensaje de Error**

> Calling error for procedure 'gimp-text-fontname':
>   Procedure 'gimp-text-fontname' has been called with value 'Stackoverflow en espaÃ' for argument 'text' (#5, type gchararray). This value is out of range.

**Ambiente**

SO: Windows 10

Python-GIMP:

```
print(sys.version)
2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Codificar:

```
texto_completo = texto.encode('utf-8')
```

2) Decodificar

```
texto_completo.decode('utf-8')
```

Referencia: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

Si la consola de GIMP trata bien los caracteres en UTF-8, te bastará con utilizar [utilizar el literal de Unicode](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).  Es decir, vez de hacer esto:

```
efecto_escritura(58,209,(255, 255, 255), 'Stackoverflow en español')
```

Simplemente cambiarlo por esto:

```
efecto_escritura(58,209,(255, 255, 255), u'Stackoverflow en español')
```

La diferencia está en la `u` delante de las comillas.

Comment: Siguiendo tu sugerencia no me genera error, pero en lugar de ñ obtengo Ã± es decir, resultado final:  Stackoverflow en espaÃ±ol

Comment: Entonces la consola de Gimp está interpretando el teclado como ISO-8859-1 (ó -15), o quizá el intérprete de Python embebido en Gimp está configurado para dicho mapa de caracteres por defecto.